# Cocos2d, How Set Device Orientation to portrait IOS

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x-3.0

I had followed this http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Device_Orientation

but my RootViewController.mm not exactly look like that.

After i replace 
'UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown'
to 'UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait' there is some error on main.m

my cocos2d version = cocos2d-x-3.13.1 , on iPhone 7 simulator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to go to xcode project setting and choose device orientation.
Here is a screenshot.

[image]